# How to stop flash and javascript on any browser page except the currently viewed one

Tags: browser, cpu, flash, javascript

I'm fed up with browsers eating up CPU cycles by running useless flash and javascript. This question is related to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/48076/how-to-prevent-flash-and-javascript-from-consuming-my-cpu) but it's slightly different.

Is it possible to automatically switch all scripts off except the ones on the currently focused (currently viewed) page?

Answer (score 2):

For firefox you can use [flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433) this blocks all flashes on all tabs, than if you want to play a flash from one tab you simply click play button. With flashblock you can play only the flash you want to.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox use [Noscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722).
By default it does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

[NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722) would work, but when you move between pages you would have to revoke the page permissions from the page (or tab) you're leaving and give permission to the page you're moving too.

Flash and Javascript don't eat many CPU cycles unless they are doing something rather intensive (like playing a movie or running an application). Stopping those in their tracks might have adverse effects to whatever is running in that window. Most well designed sites limit the Flash and Javascript usage to small portions or provide that they don't continuously run in a loop.